# Copy of folder of one document library into same document library SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library

I need to Copy folder of document library into same document library using sharePoint designer.

Folder -->Subfolder A ,Subfolder B

Need copy of Folder along with Subfolders in same Document Library.

I tried Using copyTo but it is only for a specific file.

Answer (score 1):

Using Internet Explorer, you can open the library with Explorer. When you're in explorer, create the new folder and copy your documents there.

[image]

Comment: I need to do that only with a sharepoint designer using a workflow.